# Error NODE: error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module

Tags: nodejs

tengo este archivo index.ts:

```
import Server from './classes/server';
import userRoutes from './routes/usuario';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const server = new Server();

server.app.use('/user', userRoutes)

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/bd_fotosgram');

server.start( () => {
//console.log(`Servidor corriendo en puerto ${ server.port }`);
console.log(`Servidor corriendo en puerto`);
});
```

Y me da error en la linea 3 "import mongoose from 'mongoose';". El error es este:

index.ts:3:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'mongoose'. 'C:/Users/User_1/curso_node/fotosgram/node_modules/mongoose/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/mongoose` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mongoose';`

3 import mongoose from 'mongoose';
~~~~~~~~~~

[00:33:07] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.

No sé cuál es el motivo del error.

Comment: Si instalas los tipos que te genera en el error. ```npm install @types/mongoose```

Comment: OK! acaon de instalar eso y me ha funcionado. Yo pensaba que había instalado mongoose, pero qué es eso  de los "tipos"?

Comment: Son las definiciones de los objetos de el componente.

Comment: ok. Gracias. Cómo puedo cerrar la pregunta si ya ha sido solucionada?

Comment: pon tu solución, lo que hiciste